# Can bright green avocados be ripe?

Tags: fruit, ripe, avocados

I very rarely buy avocado, but now I happen to have two of them in my kitchen.

I'm used to ripe avocado having this colour:

[image: Dark green avocado (almost black)]

Now, mine are more brightly green, like this:

[image: Bright green avocado]

They aren't very soft, so I guess they aren't ripe yet, but I'm wondering if the colour will change or if this is just a matter of which variety of avocado it is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most avocado's are the Hass variety, which will go very dark when ripe

It look like you have bought a Reed or maybe Gwen variety. They are perfectly fine. Their skin colour will not significantly change as they ripen, so to check, gently squeeze near the point, and if it is soft it is ripe. If not a few days by the window at room temperature will fix it

Answer (score 1):

The skin color of avocado comes from the variety, not ripeness. The only way to tell if one is ripe is how soft it is.